# Abstract Unix socket between C and Go

Tags: c, sockets, go, unix

I'm using an abstract Unix socket for passing data between a C and Go program. The C program is creating the socket and the Go program connects to it. The issue is the Go program fails to connect to the socket, and I receive the following error message:

```
UDS connection failed: dial unixgram @uds-js: connect: connection refused
```

Here is the C program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Buffer size for the receive socket */
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

/* The abstract Unix domain socket address name */
#define UDS_ADDRESS_NAME "#uds-js"

int main() {
    int socket_fd;
    int bytes_received;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_un server_address;
    struct sockaddr_un client_address;
    socklen_t address_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);

    /* Create local unix socket */
    if ( ( socket_fd = socket ( AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ) ) < 0 ) {
        printf ( "socket error\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    /* Set an abstract socket address */
    memset( &server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address) );
    server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy( server_address.sun_path, UDS_ADDRESS_NAME );
    server_address.sun_path[0] = '\0';

    /* Bind socket to address */
    if ( bind ( socket_fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_address, address_length ) < 0 ) {
        close ( socket_fd );
        printf ( "socket bind error\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    bytes_received =
            recvfrom(
                socket_fd,
                &buffer,
                BUFFER_SIZE,
                0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &client_address,
                &address_length );
    printf ( "Received: %s\n", buffer );
    return 0;
}
```

And the Go program:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    addr, _ := net.ResolveUnixAddr("unixgram", "@uds-js")
    udsSock, err := net.DialUnix("unixgram", nil, addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("UDS connection failed: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer udsSock.Close()
    if _, err := udsSock.Write([]byte("{\"test\":100}")); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to send message on UDS: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

In the C program I set the first byte in the socket name to a null byte, [as to spec](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html). From what I've gathered [in Go](https://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/92025745979/pitfall-of-abstract-unix-domain-socket-address-in) the name needs to start with a `@`.

Running `netstat` I can see the socket was created:

```
$ netstat -ax | grep DGRAM
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12411992 @uds-js@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Why does the Go program fail to connect to the socket?

**EDIT:**

Changing the name to a pathname, `/tmp/uds-js`, and this does work as expected.

**EDIT2:**

I created a server in Go and a client in C for the abstract socket and the two C programs and the two Go programs work okay together. The issue seem to be when going from C to Go using abstract sockets.

Comment: Does it work if you make the socket not abstract (that is, so it has a real path on a filesystem)? That would dissect the problem into two smaller parts.

Comment: also its good practice to remove the socket path on starting: remove( UDS_ADDRESS_NAME ), because you wont be able to use it if it already exists. Dont know about the # at the beginning of the path  either, does that work ?

Comment: @secretsquirrel, abstract sockets go away as soon as all references to them are lost; that's their upside compared to "classical" UD sockets.

Comment: oh yes youre right I've never used them before

Comment: Are you sure the address length is correct? Abstract addresses are **not** null-terminated! (But since it doesn't work for non-abstract sockets either, this isn't your only problem)

Comment: (If you look at netstat you can see the length is wrong. Your socket is not called @uds-js but @uds-js@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@...)

Comment: When you change it to /tmp/uds-js, does the file /tmp/uds-js get created?

Comment: @user253751, when changing to `/tmp/uds-js` the file is not created.

Comment: You deleted `server_address.sun_path[0] = '\0';` when you changed it to `/tmp/uds-js`, right?

Comment: @user253751, duh, I did not. I tried again and it worked as expect this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Go program is connecting to the wrong abstract socket (or, equivalently, the C program is binding to the wrong abstract socket).

Your `bind()` is made against an abstract namespace UNIX socket address of length `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`.  If I am [reading the Go implementation correctly](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/66190/3/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go), however, your `connect()` is performed against a socket address of length nine:  two bytes for `sa_family`, and seven bytes, in this case, for `len(name)`.

Those are different sockets.

In the abstract namespace, NULLs aren't special, so `"\0uds-js"` is one valid socket address, and `"\0uds-js\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..."` is a different valid address.

*strace* both processes looking at the C program's `bind()` and the Go program's `connect()`.  I expect you will see that they call those functions with different `socklen_t` arguments.

Comment: That indeed was the issue. In the C program I changed the address length to 9 and it worked. Looking at netstat output the name now shows as `@uds-js`, no more trailing nulls.

Comment: @dangeroushobo it should be `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_name[7])`